# Alfresco workflow assign not working

Tags: java, alfresco, alfresco-share

In Alfresco community edition-5.1.x  using custom workflow  In workflow task assignation to group or individual not working please help me out

### My Bpmn20.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<definitions xmlns="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:activiti="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:omgdc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:omgdi="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" typeLanguage="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" expressionLanguage="http://www.w3.org/1999/XPath" targetNamespace="http://www.activiti.org/test">
  <process id="mentoraTraining" name="TrainingRequest" isExecutable="true">
    <startEvent id="start" activiti:formKey="mentoratraining:start"></startEvent>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow1" sourceRef="start" targetRef="userTask1"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="userTask1" name="Operations" activiti:formKey="mentoratraining:operations" activiti:candidateGroups="${bpm_groupAssignee.properties.authorityName}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
if (typeof bpm_workflowPriority != 'undefined') task.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;;
]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_needtocoverprerequisites') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_needtocoverprerequisites', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_needtocoverprerequisites'));
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_desiredoutcomesforstudents') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_desiredoutcomesforstudents', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_desiredoutcomesforstudents'));

]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow2" sourceRef="userTask1" targetRef="userTask2"></sequenceFlow>
    <userTask id="userTask2" name="Recruitment " activiti:formKey="mentoratraining:recruitment">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:taskListener event="create" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
if (typeof bpm_workflowDueDate != 'undefined') task.dueDate = bpm_workflowDueDate;
if (typeof bpm_workflowPriority != 'undefined') task.priority = bpm_workflowPriority;;
]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
        <activiti:taskListener event="complete" class="org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.tasklistener.ScriptTaskListener">
          <activiti:field name="script">
            <activiti:string><![CDATA[
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_trainername') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_trainername', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_trainername'));
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_rateperhour') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_rateperhour', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_rateperhour'));
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_coursedurationhours') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_coursedurationhours', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_coursedurationhours'));
if (typeof task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_costoftrainer') != undefined) execution.setVariable('mentoratraining_costoftrainer', task.getVariableLocal('mentoratraining_costoftrainer'));

]]></activiti:string>
          </activiti:field>
        </activiti:taskListener>
      </extensionElements>
    </userTask>
    <sequenceFlow id="sequenceFlow3" sourceRef="userTask2" targetRef="serviceTask1"></sequenceFlow>

  </process>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_mentoraTraining">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane bpmnElement="mentoraTraining" id="BPMNPlane_mentoraTraining">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="event1" id="BPMNShape_event1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="1075.0" y="140.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusiveGateway2" id="BPMNShape_exclusiveGateway2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="1070.0" y="0.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="exclusiveGateway1" id="BPMNShape_exclusiveGateway1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="40.0" width="40.0" x="980.0" y="65.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="serviceTask1" id="BPMNShape_serviceTask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="380.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="start" id="BPMNShape_start">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="0.0" y="70.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="userTask1" id="BPMNShape_userTask1">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="80.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="userTask3" id="BPMNShape_userTask3">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="530.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="serviceTask2" id="BPMNShape_serviceTask2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="680.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="end" id="BPMNShape_end">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="30.0" width="30.0" x="1160.0" y="5.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="userTask2" id="BPMNShape_userTask2">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="230.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape bpmnElement="userTask4" id="BPMNShape_userTask4">
        <omgdc:Bounds height="60.0" width="100.0" x="830.0" y="55.0"></omgdc:Bounds>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow5" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow5">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="630.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="680.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow6" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow6">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="780.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="830.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow3" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow3">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="330.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="380.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow4" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow4">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="480.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="530.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow1" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow1">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="30.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="80.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow2" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow2">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="180.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="230.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow10" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow10">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1110.0" y="20.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1122.0" y="20.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1122.0" y="20.000000000000004"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1160.0" y="20.000000000000004"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow9" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow9">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1020.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1032.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1032.0" y="20.000000000000004"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1070.0" y="20.000000000000004"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow7" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow7">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="930.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="980.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge bpmnElement="sequenceFlow8" id="BPMNEdge_sequenceFlow8">
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1020.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1032.0" y="85.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1032.0" y="155.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
        <omgdi:waypoint x="1075.0" y="155.0"></omgdi:waypoint>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</definitions>
```

## And my model.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<model xmlns="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0" name="mentoratraining:model">
    <imports>
        <import prefix="d" uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dictionary/1.0"/>
        <import prefix="cm" uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/content/1.0"/>
        <import prefix="bpm" uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0"/>
    </imports>
    <namespaces>
        <namespace prefix="mentoratraining" uri="http://www.alfresco.org/model/dynamic-workflow/mentoratraining/1.0"/>
    </namespaces>

    <types>
        <type name="mentoratraining:operations">
            <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
             <properties/>
            <associations/>
            <overrides>
                <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                    <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
                <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                    <default>edit_and_remove_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>
            <mandatory-aspects>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestdate</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestorcompany</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestorname</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestoremail</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:trainingtopic</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:modeoftraining</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:country</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:traininglocation</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestedstartdate</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:expecteddurationinhoursperday</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:expecteddurationtotalhours</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:timingrestrictionsifany</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:classtimingincludingtimezone</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:numberofstudents</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:needtocoverprerequisites</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:desiredoutcomesforstudents</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:mlpoc</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:trainingbudget</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requestedcurriculumtopics</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requiredoperatingsystem</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requiredsoftware</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:requiredhardware</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:hardwaredetails</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:softwaredetails</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:operatingsystemdetails</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:details</aspect>
                <aspect>mentoratraining:selectgroup</aspect>
                <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>
            </mandatory-aspects>
        </type>

</model>
```

### finally my share-config-custom.xml code

```
<config >
   <forms>
      <form>
         <field-visibility>
            <show id="bpm:groupAssignee" />
             </field-visibility>
      </form>
   </forms>
</config>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add,  `<aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>` in your task.

```
      <type name="mentoratraining:operations">
            <parent>bpm:workflowTask</parent>
             <properties/>
            <associations/>
            <overrides>
                <property name="bpm:packageActionGroup">
                    <default>add_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
                <property name="bpm:packageItemActionGroup">
                    <default>edit_and_remove_package_item_actions</default>
                </property>
            </overrides>
            <mandatory-aspects>
                  <!-- Your existing aspects goes here -->
                <aspect>bpm:groupAssignee</aspect>                
            </mandatory-aspects>
        </type>
```